# How to combine values from different JSON objects to one line of CSV using jq

Tags: json, csv, jq

I want to extract data from a JSON file and write it to a CSV file using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq).

This is a sample of my data:

```
[
  {
    "media": {
      "track": [
        {
          "attype": "General",
          "FileExtension": "MP4",
          "Format": "MPEG-4"
        },
        {
          "attype": "Video",
          "Format": "MPEG Video"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "media": {
      "track": [
        {
          "attype": "General",
          "FileExtension": "ts",
          "Format": "MPEG-TS"
        },
        {
          "attype": "Video",
          "Format": "MPEG Video"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

This is the desired output:

```
"MP4","MPEG-4","MPEG Video"
"ts","MPEG-TS","MPEG Video"
```

This is my [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) code:

```
.[].media.track[] |
  [
    (select(.attype =="General") | .FileExtension, .Format),
    (select(.attype =="Video") | .Format)
  ] | @csv
```

This is the actual output:

```
"MP4","MPEG-4"
"MPEG Video"
"ts","MPEG-TS"
"MPEG Video"
```

I have experimented with the `flatten` filter and with different usage of the square brackets `[]` for array construction, but to no avail. How can I reach the desired output with [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track (pun intended) -- you just have to expand .track as follows:

```
.[].media.track
| [.[]
   | (select(.attype =="General") | .FileExtension, .Format),
     (select(.attype =="Video") | .Format) ]
| @csv
```

#### Alternatively ...

If you find all those brackets and parentheses to be too distracting, you could go with:

```
.[].media.track
| map( if .attype =="General" then .FileExtension, .Format
       elif .attype =="Video" then .Format
       else empty
       end )
| @csv
```

Comment: Why does `... track | [ .[] ... ]` provide different output from `... track[] | [ ... ]` ?

Comment: One way to understand the difference is to insert `debug` statement(s).

Comment: @vintnes both righthand filters create an array. In the first case, the filter is called once and has the whole track array as input. In the second case the filter is called once per element of the track array and only has this element as input

Answer (score 3):

A solution is to create a cells array for each media rather than for each track :

```
.[].media | 
  [ 
    .track[] |
       (select(.attype =="General") | .FileExtension, .Format),
       (select(.attype =="Video") | .Format)
  ] | @csv
```